# How to use instanceof with a class which is not defined in the current context?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

This is going to be a bit tricky but I'll do my best to explain,

Consider the following code:

```
class A { a() { return true; } }

class B { b() { return new A(); } }

var b = new B();
console.log(b instanceof B);     // true
console.log(b.b() instanceof A); // true <--- [1]
```

It's pretty straightforward to see that `(class B).b()` is going to return an instance of an object of type(/class) `A`. And we can evaluate this using the `instanceof` operator `[1]`.

Now, a problem arises when, for whatever reason, we do not have a definition for class `A` in our current scope. One scenario where such thing may happen, is when you import/require an object from a library and many of its internal classes are not exposed.

Since there is no definition for `A`, it is not possible to do `<symbol> instanceof A` ...

So, how may one actually perform this check under such scenario?

PS: I already tried the Object.prototype.toString... trick to not avail.

Comment: Maybe `b.b().constructor.name === "A"`, this won't check inherited constructors though (eg: if class A extended class X, `b.b() instanceof X` will give true, while this method will give false)

Comment: You are right and, unfortunately, in my particular scenario I'm actually looking for something like that `X`, since it's a class that extends another one.

Comment: How about this? class A { a() { return true; } }

class B extends A { b() { return new A(); } }

var b = new B();
console.log(b instanceof B);     // true
console.log(b.b() instanceof A); // true <--- [1]
console.log(b instanceof A); // true <--- [1]

Comment: Even though you won't have A in the current context, if your B extends A it will always be its child!

Comment: Why would you need to test if something is an instance of a class you can't access?

Comment: "*many of its internal classes are not exposed*" - if the classes are internal to the library, that means you *should not* check whether something is an instance of them. Please share more details about your concrete problem if "*don't use `instanceof`*" is not a solution for you.

Comment: "Why live if you are going to die?" I don't know dudes, but my question is very specific and I'm looking for those specific answers. Go chit-chat somewhere else :)

Comment: @almosnow Your question is literally "*it is not possible to do `… instanceof A`, so, how may one perform this anyway?*"! The answer is that it's impossible to do exactly what `instanceof` does without a constructor. Now there are ways to circumvent the non-exposure of the class that would allow you to still get a reference to it, and there are ways to distinguish instances by their constructors' names, and there are alternative designs where you don't need `instanceof` at all, but which of them applies to your situation we cannot tell.

Answer (score 2):

You could create a function that traverses the prototype chain and returns a list of all the super classes of an object including the class from which the object was instantiated from.

```js
class Foo {}
class X extends Foo{}
class A extends X{}

class B { b() { return new A(); } }

function getParents(obj) {
  const arr = [];

  while (obj = Reflect.getPrototypeOf(obj)) {
    arr.push(obj.constructor.name);
  }  
    
  return arr;
}

var b = new B().b();
const parents = getParents(b);

console.log(`b instance of A = ${parents.includes('A')}`);
console.log(`b instance of X = ${parents.includes('X')}`);
console.log(`b instance of Foo = ${parents.includes('Foo')}`);
console.log(`b instance of Object = ${parents.includes('Object')}`);
```

You could also do this using a recursive function

```js
class Foo {}
class X extends Foo{}
class A extends X{}


class B { b() { return new A(); } }

function getParents(obj, arr = null) {
  if (!arr) arr = [];
  
  const protoTypeObj = Reflect.getPrototypeOf(obj);
  if (!protoTypeObj) return;
  
  arr.push(protoTypeObj.constructor.name);
  
  getParents(protoTypeObj, arr);
  
  return arr;
}

var b = new B().b();
const parents = getParents(b);

console.log(`b instance of A = ${parents.includes('A')}`);
console.log(`b instance of X = ${parents.includes('X')}`);
console.log(`b instance of Foo = ${parents.includes('Foo')}`);
console.log(`b instance of Object = ${parents.includes('Object')}`);
```

Comment: Why make it recursive when a simple loop would suffice? :D

Comment: @Bergi yes ofcourse, didn't think of this at the time of answering the question :P Added another snippet that uses a loop.